# How can I set the IFS to be a comma followed with a space?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ifs

I want to separate words when there is a comma that is followed up by a space.

I have tried
`IFS=', '`
but it separates if there is a comma or space not when they are together.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: That's not how `IFS` is used. It's basically a list of possible single-character field separators, not a single multi-character string.

Comment: What should I use to separate with multi character string?